# How do I stripslashes from something I include in PHP?

Tags: php

I am working on a website and I have a php editor that automatically adds \ to certain things. I was aware of the `stripslashes()` function and I know it can be used in a way such as: `stripslashes($test)` but I am including something and I do not know how to strip the slashes from the Page I am including. Here is my include code that I am using:

```
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/newseditor/BlogTitle.php"; ?>
```

So how would I stripslashes from this? Thanks for reading and I appreciate all help I recieve.

Comment: It sounds like you need to disable MAGIC_QUOTES.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.whynot.php -- explains why you should *not* use MAGIC_QUOTES.

Comment: Is there another way of doing that?

Comment: No, there isn't. Do the right thing, disable magic quotes, preferably via PHP ini settings, if not possible then you have to filter the input variables $_POST and $_GET (only if the option is set). See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are suffering from PHP's magic quotes, and here is how to turn it off:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Comment: I get a 500 internal server error when disabling through .htaccess.

Comment: Talk to your hosting company to have the setting disabled. They probably have a FAQ for this common question. And .htaccess is not the only solution mentioned on the page.